# Fix for mutating while enumerating issue in core data

Tags: ios, multithreading, core-data

I am currently doing project that downloads from an external server. Then I do JSON serialization which will then be saved to the core data database. I receive an error

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: '*** Collection <__NSCFSet: 0x69c8a10> was mutated while being enumerated.
```

which is pointed to a line of code that I use as part of querying the database which is:

`NSArray *matches = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];`

Full code I use in querying the database:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Product"];
request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"product_id = %@", [productInfo  objectForKey:@"id"]];
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
request.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];
NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *matches = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
```

I only pass around an object that contains a single UIManagedDocument. I have gone through different posts here in SO regarding the same problem and a lot of people pointed out that it is a threading issue.

Mostly, they suggest to have a sort of a parent-and-child context which will be on separate threads; one context will take care of downloading stuff, the other will be on the main thread that will take care of UI. Then changes done will be merged later. We're already on the process of starting it yet this proposed solution seemed to have a lot of issues as said in this [***post***](http://wbyoung.tumblr.com/post/27851725562/core-data-growing-pains) by Whitney Young. Such issues were, and I quote

- Child contexts block ancestors
- Making changes into a parent context can be slow
- Fetch results are wrong in a child context
- Cannot access relationship in a child context for unsaved objects
- Sorting is not honored when there are changes in a parent context
- NSFetchedResultsController deadlocks

These seems to be a real pain @_@, so if any of you guys have some other great ideas on how to do this will be greatly recognized. Thanks SO people!

Comment: Contexts explicitly aren't thread safe; there are therefore no meaningful ideas that don't involve either multiple contexts or simply not doing any Core Data work off the main thread. For the record, having been architected in from the start my project's stuff for managing multiple contexts with multiple roles and appropriate synchronisation is less than 500 lines.

Comment: Thanks for the urgent reply @Tommy , whoa less than 500 lines, pretty intense stuff. Have you experienced any of the above-mentioned issues before? And ah, if you have any helpful tutorials I can study on, may I humbly request some links.